# Animating the background of the ActionBar (ProgressView)

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-animation

I'm trying to figure out how to do this.  I want my actionBar's background color to animate like a progress bar.  Like some sort of gradient animation.

Here's an example of a similar behavior on iOS:  http://youtu.be/LFq311lOuGo (around 0:10 sec)

Any ideas on how to achieve something similar on Android?  Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I actually wrote a Gist for this not too long ago. https://gist.github.com/adneal/6210163

Comment: This is great!  Quick question though, how do I set the background color?  I can animate the background (green as per your example), but the rest of the bar is always white. Any ideas?

Comment: Ah ha, I got it!  Just need to add a canvas.drawColor() before the call to canvas.drawRect in the answer.  Accepting this as the correct answer!